# Can I read text from console application during console still runing process?

Tags: c#, process, console

I use `ProcessStartInfo` to run a console aplication and `ProcessStartInfo` can read text from the console after the console is closed:

```
using (Process p = Process.Start(st))
{
    //Thread.Sleep(2000);
    p.WaitForExit();
    using (StreamReader rd = p.StandardOutput)
    {
        result = rd.ReadToEnd();
        p.Close();

        String result1 = String.Copy(result);    
    }
```

Is there another method to read text from the console while it is open?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`OutputDataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Process` class

```
string result = string.Empty;
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = st; // your ProcessStartInfo
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        st.AppendLine(e.Data);
    };

    process.Start();

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
    result = resultBuilder.ToString();
}
```

You simply add an event handler to the `Process`'s `OutputDataReceived` event that gets called whenever the process outputs a line.
Then you need to call [`BeginOutputReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx) *after* the process has been started to begin receiving those events.

---

In this example, I still wait for the process to exit just to complete the code. Of course you don't need to wait, the events occure while the process is running. So you can store your `process` variable in a member and dispose it later or even subscribe to its [`Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event to get informed when the process terminates.